# Angular dependency injection. what the hell am i doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, dependencies

Here's a simple example of what i'm trying to do. I'll preface this by saying that i have been working as a maintainer for 3 weeks on an already built project in angular, and i have a minor, at best understanding of angular to date. i can work with the controllers and views and models, all that is fine. but when it comes time to understanding the dependency injection, i am stymied by vague errors. Now it's came time i need to learn about how the Injector works, so here's a small test app i have constructed for my own learning purposes. i do not actually know if this is the correct way to build an angular app at all. The documentation i find confusing at best.

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="EC as e">
</div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $window) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'bearer '+ $window.localStorage.token;
                return config;
            }
        };
    });
}]);

function EC($scope,$http,$window) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.api = function( resource ){
        return ('https://api.website.com/v1/'+resource).replace('//','/');
    };

    $window.localStorage.token = 'foobar';

    $http.put( vm.api('/users/me'), { loggedIn: true }).then(function(response){

        $http.get( vm.api('/users/me') ).then.function(response){
            vm.user = response.data;
        });

    });

}

EC.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$window'];

app.controller('EC',EC);

app.run();
```

I had assumed the line `EC.$inject = ['$scope','$http','$window'];` would insure that my controllers constructor would be called with those services, or whatever the hell they are called, as arguments. Apparently thats not the case. Can someone explain to me like i'm 5 how this works, and why i'm getting an error?

Error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just bad markup.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/ezyghn06/) showing you working code

Change:

```
   .then
      .function(response) {
        vm.user = response.data;
```

to

```
   .then(function(response) {
        vm.user = response.data;
```

Comment: the actual problem is that i did not know i had to include extra files for $http to be available. your fiddle shows what is wrong actually, but in a different way. the code i provided is just a dummy, so the syntax error was a red herring in my effort to make a brief example illustrating the problem. after applying the missing resources, my code does now work. i appreciate your effort.

Comment: This was 100% your injection issue.  I have no doubt there are other things wrong with the code.

Comment: And you don't have include other files for $http

Comment: well, it still doesn't run for me. i copy everything exactly and it won't run. the error i get now is "cannot find module app"

Comment: What did you copy?   Can't find module `app` probably means you are trying to look up the module before declaring it.  The fiddle should be proof your code works fine once you fix the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote the controller block to follow more conventionaly injection. Might workout for ya. Also removed the double response callback from the $http calls and returned the $http.get() promise.

```
angular.module('app', [])



.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider)
{
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($window) 
  {
    return {
      request: function(config) 
      {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'bearer '+ $window.localStorage.token;
        return config;
      }
    };
  });
}])



.controller('EC', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http, $window) 
{
  var buildApiString = function(resource)
  {
    return ('https://api.website.com/v1/'+resource).replace('//','/');
  };


  $window.localStorage.token = 'foobar';


  $http.put(buildApiString('/users/me'), { loggedIn: true }).then(function()
  {
    return $http.get(buildApiString('/users/me')).then(function(response)
    {
      $scope.user = response.data
    });
  });
}]);
```